# Gnome Shell Integration in Firefox 51 not working

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-3

I'm trying to use install an extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/ using Firefox 51 on 16.04. I followed the instructions and installed the Gnome Shell Integration as well as chrome-gnome-shell. However, when opening https://extensions.gnome.org/ I still get a hint to install the above:

[image: The problem.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this instruction](https://github.com/nE0sIghT/chrome-gnome-shell-mirror/issues/34#issuecomment-281675397) and post output here.

If you are getting "shell_version.unpack(), Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unpack'" error, then you are not using GNOME Shell.

Obviously GNOME Shell extension and GNOME Shell integration works **only** with GNOME Shell.